# How to add 2 conf in SparkContext() function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I tried the following:

```
conf = (
        SparkConf().set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0"),
        SparkConf().set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")        
        )
        
     
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

However, i got the folllowing error:
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'`

This works:

```
conf = (
        SparkConf().set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0")     
        )
        
     
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i think this worked:

```
conf = (
        pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0"),("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1") ])       
        )

        
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
conf = SparkConf()
conf = conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0")
conf = conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

or

```
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0").set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

both ways are possible (and actually identical)

also `set` may be used without `conf` variable reinitialization:

```py
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0")
conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```